# Is it possible to use code completion and see API documentation for Node.js in Node eclipse?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node eclipse with node.js and express.js installed but I'm having a hard time learning the APIs without these features. Please guide on the best options available. I am a java developer and I'm somewhat used to conventional code completion and javadocs as in java+eclipse. Please guide.

Comment: Don't know. But you should try Jetbrains WebStorm with Node.js plugin - it's awesome! If you have IntelliJ IDEA or PhpStorm it's even better. PS: I'm not connected to Jetbrains.

Comment: I dont see a nodeJS plugin for IntelliJIDEA. Can you point me to it? I tried the plugin on this page but it doesn't work. http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098

Comment: File > Settings > Plugins > [Install JetBrains plugin...] > (search for nodejs) > (choose NodeJS, right-click) > Install Plugin > (restart IDE). If it doesn't work, your IDEA version might be too old?!